# Why can't I assign a Map variable to an AbstractSeq variable in Scala?

Tags: scala

I want to declare a variable of type `AbstractSeq[(String, Integer)]` which will store a list of pairs. Then depending on the program flow, I might assign an `ArrayBuffer[(String, Integer)]` to it, or a `Map[String, Integer]`:

```
val map: Map[String, Integer] = Map("Alice" -> 10, "Bob" -> 3, "Cindy" -> 8)
var lst: AbstractSeq[(String, Integer)] = List.empty
...
lst = map # compile error
```

But I get the following error:

```
found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Integer]
required: scala.collection.immutable.AbstractSeq[(String, Integer)]
```

**My question:** Why do I get this error? Isn't `Map` just an AbstractSeq of pairs, and thus I should be able to do this?

**What I've tried:** I have googled around for this error and related keywords, and haven't found an answer to my question.

**Why I'm asking:** I'm trying to understand the relationship between different Collection types in Scala. Which Collection types can be assigned to variables of which types, and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [`Map[K, +V]`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html) is not an `AbstractSeq`:

```scala
trait Map[K, +V] extends Iterable[(K, V)] with collection.Map[K, V] with MapOps[K, V, Map, Map[K, V]] with MapFactoryDefaults[K, V, Map, Iterable]
```

Docs have [collection overview](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html) which can shed some light one relationships between different collection types.

Comment: Thanks Guru! Is there some type of existing class that both `List[String, Integer]` and `collection.Map[(String, Integer)]` are both subclasses of?

Comment: For some extra context, I'm asking because I am reading "Scala for the Impatient", which mentions that a Map is basically just a Collection of pairs, which made me think it subclasses some kind of higher level "collection of pairs" class, which would also be a superclass of `List[String, Integer]`

Comment: @Cam you can try `Iterable[(String, Integer)]`